# Why is there an infinity here? Potential paradox

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, singularities

Edit: i guess it must be infinity on second thought?

I have been having some problems with the potential formula, giving undefined results. I am obviously overlooking something obvious

Consider the example, where I have a line charge. the with a charge density $\lambda$ that is straight in the $x$ direction

$\vec{r}=  x \hat i$

$\vec{r}' = x' \hat i$

This would evaluate the potential along the axis of the line charge

$|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'| = |x-x'|$

the potential function for a line charge that starts from $x = 0$ to $x = L$

would be

$ \int_{0}^{l} \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\lambda}{|x-x'|} dx' $

Now,

when $(x>x') : |x-x'|= x-x'$

when $(x<x'): |x-x'|= x'-x $

Thus to generalise this function to allow for both,(aka evaluating the potential inside the line charge)the integral would be

$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\lambda}{x-x'} dx' $ +$ \int_{x}^{l} \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\lambda}{x'-x} dx'$

Assume I want to evaluate the potential on the coordinate x = 0

the first integral has bounds 0 to 0 so is zero,

Doing the second integration we are left with the function

$V(x) = \frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}ln(x' -x) $ Evaluated at x to l

Plugging in the bounds

$ V(x) = \frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}ln(L -x) - \frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}ln(x -x) $

First of all, the second term has ln(0) in it which means it is undefined ( or negative infinity)

So my question is, is this correct or where have I gone wrong, as clearly the potential is defined, and isn't infinity

edit: I'm pretty sure with this the answer lies in the fact that the first integral is indeterminate  and the addition of these gives a finite result. But consider where x is always greater than x'  you'd use the left hand integral from bounds zero to l, When x=l the function also diverges

Also in general when r'= r the denominator for the integral is zero so what about the integral fixes this issue. so the contribution is undefined. This doesn't normally be an issue as normally the denominator doesn't tend to zero  unless e.g The potential inside charge distribution

At first I thought the first integral on the left  might help us resolve the infinity but consider -

$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\lambda}{|x-x'|} dx' $

Here this represents a potential function who's line length grows depending on the position I evaluate it at ( aka as more  and more charge builds up, what's the new potential at the point where I add a new dq of charge, this is what led me to this problem when considering potential energy of a system)

Here, x is always greater or equal to x' this integral reduces to

$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\lambda}{x-x'} dx' $

There is also an infinity here  with no help from the other integral that could "fix it",

Help!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the potential inside of a 1 dimensional object, which doesn't exist in a 3d world.

If you're really interested in getting the potential inside of a charged slim/long object, change the charge distribution to a very thin cylinder

$$ \rho(p, \theta, z) = \Theta(p - R) \Theta(z - z')\frac{1}{p}$$
and take R to be as small as you want.